# Can I get consistent CSS colors across browsers?

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, colors

I'm testing a new site, and I have a div with

```
background-color: #bbf6bb;
```

That seems innocuous enough to me. And yet, on my MacBook Pro, the color looks very different in Firefox 3.6 vs. Safari 4. In Safari, it's the color I'd expect from the hex value: a pale green. In Firefox, there's a definite bluish tint, making the color turquoise.

I'm aware of color inconsistencies that result from different treatment of images across browsers, but in pure CSS? Really? I'm guessing that Firefox trying to correct for my display in hopes of delivering better consistency with print, but I'd much rather have my site look the same hue to my users regardless of their choice of browser. Any ideas? Can someone confirm that Firefox is the culprit here?

[Update: This seems to have been a fluke. Specifically, it's a narrow issue with Firefox—see my answer below. I'm puzzled, but relieved.]

Comment: Does your style tag have the "media=screen" attribute?

Comment: As I said in the comment to my answer, can you create a screen shot of this? This is really strange.

Comment: I wish I'd taken a screenshot at the time, because now I find myself unable to reproduce the issue. I'm sure it was there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've isolated the issue! It's definitely a Firefox 3.6 bug (running on Mac OS 10.6). Seems to have something to do with having a large number of tabs open. If I create a new tab and go to the page, I get the slightly off colors (blue-green instead of just green). If I create a new window and go to the same page, the colors are accurate. And yes, this still occurs if I refresh both instances.

[**Edit**: Screenshot got misplaced, but I stand by this answer.]

Comment: Actually i don't know how you took you screen shots but the color difference is also apparent in the browser themes, so i question this test. ;)

Answer (score 4):

> but I'd much rather have my site look the same hue to my users regardless of their choice of browser.

That's just the thing - without colour correction, it *won't* look the same to different users, because not every monitor has the exact same colour response.

Comment: I don't think you read my question closely. This isn't about different monitors; I'm talking about Firefox and Safari, on the same display, with the same system settings.

Comment: Safari doesn't perform colour-correction on CSS and images without colour profiles, while Firefox assumes sRGB for those. The end result is that Firefox users get roughly the same colours across all monitors, while Safari users get completely different colours depending on what monitor they're on.

Answer (score 0):

[color managent](http://blog.duber.cz/misc/firefox-color-management-madness) color profiles not only changes the images (that can save those) but also the rgb colors.

Comment: OK, right, but differently in Firefox vs. Safari? I need a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the browser, more with the user's monitor's colour correction. Every monitor has slight differences in how they show colours; additionally, the background lighting around the monitor plays a role, as well (warm daylight vs. usually colder inside lights etc. etc).

Sadly, there's nothing really you can do. You could embed a colour profile into your graphics, which is how design professionals do it when sending data to print, but that will provide halfway decent results only for the minuscule number of (graphic designers') monitors that has undergone colour calibration and is properly set up - and I think IE won't parse colour profiles at all.

Comment: No, this has everything to do with the browser. Read the question.

Comment: @Trevor: Sorry, I didn't read your question closely enough. Now that's really odd. Can you create a screen shot showing two such inconsistencies? It would be interesting to take a look at the actual colour values.

Comment: If you don't give your images a colour profile the browser should understand them as sRGB (therefore, I always do "convert to sRGB" and strip the colour profiles when doing "save for web" in Photoshop).