# Website text color differs across platforms

Tags: html, css, windows

I have a website with text that I've set to `#666666` in CSS. This color persists just fine across browsers- however, when I view the site on a Windows machine, the text appears a much lighter shade of gray, despite my using the same browsers (Firefox and Chrome). This problem only occurs within the content elements- the nav bar is also set to `#666666` and it behaves as desired.

The CSS for the nav bar:

```
a.nav {
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

The CSS for my content (this is the stuff that changes color):

```
#content {
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    width: 470px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    line-height: 128%;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Any ideas about why this might be happening and what I can do to remedy it?

Comment: Are you using the same monitor and the exact same display settings ?

Comment: That's the colour of the devil.  It is meant to make it hell for you to figure it out :P

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135764/can-i-get-consistent-css-colors-across-browsers

Comment: Same monitor yes- I'm running a virtual machine. I've tested it on other machines as well, though, and none of the other colors change. It's just the content text becomes way lighter, almost too hard to read against the background.

Answer (score 0):

may be rgb color as it may be more consistent applied on different elements.

```
color: rgb(102,102,102);
```